# Windows 8.1 Pro change language

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I have installed Windows 8.1 Pro from MSDN. I would like to Change my Display language from german to english. In the menu, there is written "no additonal languages are avaible". Is there a way to install it manually?

thanks

Comment: You might have to wait until Windows 8.1 is released to the general public before you can do this.  If the languages are not listed within the `Control Panel` your options are limited.

Comment: I found a discussion about the LIP for win 8.1 and it would appear that it's regional and can be resolved by changing your region http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-windows_install/windows-81-language-pack/dd8f7f67-2337-4844-9e6e-d63deaf20774

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must download the ISO with the [MUI packs from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=524&Languages=en&ProductFamilyIds=524&FileExtensions=.iso&PageSize=10&PageIndex=2&FileId=0)

```
mu_windows_8_1_language_pack_x86_dvd_2706085.iso
mu_windows_8_1_language_pack_x64_dvd_2706084.iso
```

, mount the ISO and copy the MUI you want to install to the HDD. Now rename the CAB to `lp.mlc` and make a double click on the file to run setup.

Comment: worked like it should and was really easy.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can go to Control Panel.
2. Then click on View by : Category on the right upper corner.
3. Then, Under the category Clock, Language and Region, click on add a language link.
4. If you see the language you want in the list, go on step 9.
5. If you don't see the language you want in the list, click on add a language button
6. Then, click on the language you want, then on the bottom button Open.
7. Then click on the language with locale you want. Then click on Add.
8. Then, you're back on the first screen of add a language
9. Click on the link option on the right of your language
10. Then click on the first link, which should be "Download and Install language pack" or "set as primary language".
11. On next login, Windows will be in the language you want.

Comment: I wonder why this isn't the best answer. A couple of clicks and it just works.

Comment: it was spot on... I love seeing that Microsoft AT LAST made it so easy to change the installation language... once upon a time you had to reinstall the whole enchilada

Comment: Didn't work for me. Only added keyboard input language but startup and display language remain the same.

Answer (score -3):

"You'll need to download the language pack if you want to make a language your Windows display language (that's the language you see most often in Windows and apps).

Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings.
(If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, click Settings, and then click Change PC settings.)

Tap or click Time and language, and then tap or click Region and language.

Tap or click a language that says Language pack available underneath, and then tap or click Options.

Tap or click Download. The download process might take a while, depending on your PC and the size of the language pack.

If you want to make this your display language, see the next section "Change your Windows display language"."

Source:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/language-pack-in-windows-81/37872f39-2818-49c7-8ab7-410d0619669c

Comment: `If you want to make this your display language, see the next section "Change your Windows display language".` what do you mean?

Comment: This is obviously copied and pasted from somewhere. I'm going to downvote it until you post your source or adjust your answer to include all the required information.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here and didn't have the time to read all the rules. Now I have posted the source.