# How to change display language in windows 8.1?

Tags: language, windows-8.1

I installed windows 8.1 on my system, but the display language is Portugese I want to change it to English. How can I do that?

Comment: does changing language and regional settings doesnt work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know the default language settings of Windows are always in control panel. Try to go to Search > Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region >  Regional and Language Options.

Alternatively, you can just go to Search > Control Panel > [all control panel items] > Language.

[image]

Comment: Also you must consider this: http://superuser.com/questions/647567/windows-8-1-pro-change-language/668934#668934